Permission denied: users/usr/.local/bin
I'm trying to install a program to download pdf files. This is the github link https://github.com/Lofter1/anyflip-downloader. I followed the istructions but I basically don't know exaclty what I'm doing. I hava a mac so i used
 curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Lofter1/anyflip-downloader/main/scripts/install.sh | /usr/bin/env bash

but then when I try to use
$HOME/.local/bin anyflip-downloader <link>

says "zhs: permission denied Users/usr/.local/bin. Sorry if the question is silly

Assuming your'e a beginner, I'll tell you how you can run it without breaking your macOS.
cd $HOME/.local/bin
After that,
./anyflip-downloader <link>

you had to add $HOME/.local/bin in your path, not prepend in the command. Adding to path might be overwhelming for you, so it'd be better to go to the installed path and execute it. cd $HOME/.local/bin will change your directory to that, and after that, you can directly execute it.
